# Qt - Open single instance of a window

Tags: c++, qt

How do I check if a window/dialog is already open? I used this code to open a new dialog box but everytime I click it the dialog keeps on opening. Obviously not the way settings dialog works.

```
Class *someClass = new Class();
someclass->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you create a new window/widget/dialog everytime.
Initialize `*someClass` somewhere else and then only show it.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { someClass = new SomeClass() }
    void fooClicked() { someClass->show() }

private:
    SomeClass *someClass;
};
```

Comment: I agree with this approach. Would initialize someClass to 0 though and create it only when needed. Might want to call raise() then in fooClicked() in case someClass is not null.

Comment: It gives me LOADS of errors if i use this code:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11701729/Code.txt

Comment: Showing us those errors would be helpful... But you probably already have `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)` in `mainwindow.cpp`. Also, what is `Settings`?

Answer (score 1):

Use QPointer:

```
QPointer<MyDialog> dialog = new MyDialog(this);
dialog->show();
...
if (dialog) dialog->show();
```

If dialog exists it will be shown. If it is deleted in the meantime, it will hold 0 instead of an invalid address, and the last line will never be executed - it will not be shown but you can recreate it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your calling class (or main application class, or something similar) define a pointer to the class:

```
dialogclass *someclass;
```

In the constructor of that main class, initialize the dialog class:

```
someclass = NULL;
```

When you want to show the dialog, do something along these lines:

```
if (!someclass) someclass = new dialogclass();  // Creates a dialog instance if it does not already exist 
if (!someclass->isVisible()) someclass->show(); // Only shows the dialog if it is not already shown.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an static pointer on your window class. It allows you to store last opened window object.

```
class MyWindow : public QWidget {
  public :
    static MyWindow* instance;

  ...
}
```

Whenever you make a new instance you can set `instance`. When the instance is null you can make a new window. When you want to close the opened window, you should make instance null again. This allows you to have only one open window.

```
if (MyWindow::instance == NULL) {
  MyWindow *w = new MyWindow(...);
  MyWindow::instance = w;
}
```

This design pattern is called Singleton and it allows you to have only one object per a class. Also, this is a bit different because in Singleton, constructor is not public and factory method should be used for making an object but it is similar.

Comment: Doesn't seem very elegant nor flexible to me. Why make something a singleton when a (non-static) member variable in the creating class works just as good? The member also works if you want to have more than once instance of a dialog (but not necessarily in a given context).

Comment: As I said it is not Singleton. It is something like that. This implementation won't force you to have only one object. Also, the static pointer can be outside of the class. But I agree with you. Static variables shouldn't be used when local variables suffice.